# Changing the Default Property in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, attributes

I have created a asp.net Solution which has 30 webforms. By Default autocomplete is on . If i need to off the autocomplete condition for the 30 webforms. I have to add attributes(autocomplete =off) for every form .
Is there any way to off the autocomplete condition for the entire Solution ?

Comment: I didn't Use MasterPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Then try to use a BasePage and inherit all pages from it:

```
    public abstract class BasePage : Page    
    {    
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
        {    
            //Handling autocomplete issue generically    
            if (this.Form != null)    
            {    
                this.Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");    
            }

            base.OnLoad(e);    
        }    
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your pages have master page then try to disable autocomplete for input controls using Jquery in the master page.

You can place the below code in the master page:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off"); });
```

Comment: Thanks .But I didn't Use Master page .That is the Problem